# What will cause a Java class to be initialized?

Tags: java, android, classloader

I am using the [Wrapper Class method](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html) to allow me to handle a class either existing or not. When using this technique, it is important to know what will cause my `Proxy` class to be initialized. In particular, what if I:

1. Declare an instance of `Proxy` without setting it to anything

   public class myClass{
       ...
       Proxy myInst;
   }
2. Declaring an instance of `Proxy` locally inside a never run if statement

   public void myMeth{
       if(ProxyIsAvailableWhichItIsNot){
           Proxy myInst;
           ...
       }
   }

Update: As pointed out by Henning, I am interested in when a class is initialized (and static blocks run), rather than when it is loaded. I updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: It seems that I asked a similar question when I was working on [Java ME](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742499/when-does-a-dynamically-loaded-class-that-references-a-non-existent-classes-metho)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Java implementation has a choice of either *loading* a class as soon as another class that references it is *loaded*, or postponing this until it becomes necessary to *initialize* the class. In the first case, the class can sit around for a considerable amount of time (perhaps forever) being *loaded* but not *initialized*.

In contrast, there are precise rules for when a class is *initialized* (static initializers run), namely the first time an object of the class is created, or a static method called, or a non-constant static field is accessed.

The only completely sure way to prevent a JVM from trying to *load* a class is not to mention it explicitly in the code and use `Class.forName()` and reflection to request loading at some definite point in time, at which time `ClassNotFoundException` may be thrown and handled. However, modern JVMs typically load classes much more lazily than the language specification allows them to, so more optimistic strategies will often work in practice.

The "wrapper class" technique described in your link is not guaranteed to work by Java (see §12.1.2 of the Java Language Specification, 3rd edition), but it's entirely possible that Android/Dalvik gives stronger guarantees of its own.

Comment: Thanks. I did mean initializing rather than loading. So you are saying that neither of those situations should cause the class to be initialized?

Comment: Yes, but what good is that if even _loading_ your class makes the JVM throw a `NoClassDefFoundError` because the underlying class cannot be found (as the JVM is allowed, but not required, to do at that point)?

Comment: The proxy dynamically loads the (possibly) missing class in a static initialiser. So the exception occurs when the proxy is initialized, not loaded.

Comment: That's fine, then. But it's not what your link describes as a "wrapper class", thus the confusion. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

If youare using the technique listed in that URL, part of the technique involves calling the static method to validate if the class is loadable with the current APIs or not.  That allows you to do something like this:

1. Generate a boolean value, such as IsMyProxyAvailable
2. Call your static checkAvailable() method on your proxy class
3. Set the value to true when the method succeeds, false if you except when calling it.

You could also create a singleton factory for this class that handles the above check, and either returns an instantiated class when it's available, or null.   It sounds like you are wanting to avoid having to scope around the boolean, which a factory would (sort of) enable you to avoid (with a different cost).

Comment: I do have a boolean, its just that I need to keep the Proxy around for a while, so I can't just keep it locally. I just switched to using an Object and casting it locally

Comment: I'm not suggesting Object is a bad way to go, but I have found that staying strong-typed as much as possible generally results in more runtime errors caught by the compiler instead of later in the debugger.

Comment: Argh, I screwed my previous comment up in edit.

I'm a personal fan of staying strong-typed as much as possible, which would in this case probably have me using some sort of factory-style design, and probably along with an interface contract that I reference these classes with instead of the class themselves.   That would enable me to have a "Proxy" and "NoProxy" class implementing the same interface, which would solve your issue of being able to reference the class anywhere, but because you used an interface, you are able to put a no-op version in place of the real one when no methods exist.

Comment: A slightly lighter-weight solution would be to have Proxy inherit from NoProxy. Then you wouldn't need the interface

Comment: True that.   And in this case, since NoProxy is a fairly empty class, there's not a lot of inheritance danger there.   On the downside, if you are writing JUNit tests around this, injecting a class to replace Proxy/NoProxy would be extremely difficult (or impossible)

Answer (score 0):

Java has a very defined way classes are loaded.  In Java all code is loaded through a ClassLoader.  The bytes loaded by the class are kept in memory for the length of the ClassLoader instance therefore, your Class instance will live as long as the ClassLoader instance survives.  Classes can't be reloaded or redefined after being loaded without throwing away the ClassLoader that loaded it.  When a class is loaded by the ClassLoader it's static initializer blocks are called.  Therefore, class loading is basically the same time as Class initialization.

What triggers a class to be loaded?  If another class that depends on it is loaded.  When the Java compiler is compiling a class it writes into the class file all qualified classnames it depends on.  Classes are loaded as late as possible so typically this means when you instantiate them under normal conditions.  However, having static members will force those to be loaded prior to this class being loaded.  Instance members will be loaded when this class is instantiate as well.  If you want lots of good details of this process read the following:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dyn0429/

Fortunately, Dalvik VM works remarkable similar to the JVM because Java specifies this process in great detail.

With you using the Wrapper method in the static initializer if the Class.forName() succeeds it doesn't matter when how you define Proxy (option 1 or 2) because it will already be loaded.  Otherwise the parent Wrapper class won't load.  So just do option 1 since it's simpler.